# Add a prefix into routes on ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to deploy my ReactJS app on Apache Server. But I have one problem:

All my routes starts from `/` (eg: `localhost:3000/MY_INDEX`). Now, in Apache, I have my project on a subfolder so the route is `domain.com/subfolder/MY_INDEX` (so, all my routes must start with: `/subfolder/`). There is anyway to do that the root of the routes (`/`) start after `domain/subfolder` without having to change all with this prefix?.

Thank you.

EDIT:---- This is my code:

```
const history = useRouterHistory(createHistory)({
    basename: '/upct'
})

export default class IndexRoutes extends React.Component { 
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            dataLoaded: false,
            isAdmin: false,
            isAlumno: false,
            isProf: false
        }
    }

    render() {
        if (!this.state.dataLoaded) {

            return (
                <div class="text-center">Cargando...</div>
            );

        } else {

            return (
                <Router history={history}>

                    <Route path="/" component={NoEncontrado404}/>
                    <Redirect from="/alumno" to="/alumno/inicio"/>
                    <Redirect from="/administrador" to="/administrador/inicio"/>

                    <Route path="/" component={App}>

                        <Route path="administrador" component={AppAdministrador}>
                            <Route path="inicio" component={RequireAdministrador(Administrador_Inicio, this.state.isAdmin)}/>
                            <Route path="nueva_incidencia" component={RequireAdministrador(Administrador_NuevaIncidencia, this.state.isAdmin)}/>
                            <Route path="incidencias_recibidas" component={RequireAdministrador(Administrador_IncidenciasRecibidas, this.state.isAdmin)}/>
                            <Route path="incidencias_recibidas/nuevo_informe" component={RequireAdministrador(Administrador_NuevoInforme, this.state.isAdmin)}/>
                            <Route path="informes" component={RequireAdministrador(Administrador_Informes, this.state.isAdmin)}/>
                            <Route path="informes/nueva_respuesta_informe/:id" component={RequireAdministrador(Administrador_NuevaRespuestaInforme, this.state.isAdmin)}/>
                        </Route>

                        <Route path="alumno" component={AppAlumno}>
                            <Route path="inicio" component={RequireAlumno(Alumno_Inicio, this.state.isAlumno)}/>
                            <Route path="nueva_incidencia" component={RequireAlumno(Alumno_NuevaIncidencia, this.state.isAlumno)}/>
                            <Route path="mis_incidencias" component={RequireAlumno(Alumno_MisIncidencias, this.state.isAlumno)}/>
                        </Route>


                        <Route path="/profesor/informes/nueva_respuesta_informe/:id" component={RequireProfesor(Profesor_NuevaRespuestaInforme, this.state.isProf)}/>

                    </Route>

                    <Route path="/:loggedAs/acceso_restringido" component={AccesoRestringido}/>
                    <Route path='/404' component={NoEncontrado404} />

                    <Redirect from='*' to='/404' />

                {/*
                    <Route path="*" component={NoEncontrado404}/>
                */}

                </Router>
            );

        }
    }
}
```

The above code is returning me a white page, even if the route does not exit.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you must configure vhost for the your website that points on your subfolder.

Comment: I can not touch vhost. only can add .htaccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your history object with a `baseName` attribute, which in your case should have the value 'subfolder'. Then all of your in-app routes will extend from this point. For example:

```
import { useRouterHistory } from 'react-router'
import { createHistory } from 'history'

const history = useRouterHistory(createHistory)({
  basename: '/subfolder'
})

const routes = // your routes

render(
  <Router history={history} routes={routes} />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

See the [history docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history) or the [React Router docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/Histories.md#histories) for more information.

Comment: I need to do: npm install --save history, right? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, even though history is a dependency of React Router, you should install it as an explicit dependency of your own project to enable this.

Comment: OK! Thank you. I used your code but I have one problem. When loads, all routes shows in white with no content, and no error.

Comment: Even if the route does not exist, loads a white page

Comment: I added on an edit my code, due to if you want see it

Comment: Hi! I have another dude. It works correcty (I added as BASENAME: '/subfolder'. And when I go to `MyDomain/subfolder/Home` is working perfect. But if I put `MyDomain/Home` it works too. Why??? Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm out of ideas! It may be related to your Apache config.

Comment: I do not think so. It is happening on dev-server (localhost) too (`http://localhost:3000/subfolder/Home` and `http://localhost:3000/Home` both works), in Apache I have bloqued SERVER/my_route and works right so can not access to / (but if user would have access, This route will be working too)